# Зачем в классе LinkedList вызывается пустой конструктор

Tags: java, конструктор, linked-list

В Java классе `LinkedList` объявлен конструктор по умолчанию, в котором ничего не объявлено

```
/**
 * Constructs an empty list.
 */
public LinkedList() {
}
```

Также имеется конструктор, принимающий в аргументе коллекцию:

```
/**
 * Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified
 * collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's
 * iterator.
 *
 * @param  c the collection whose elements are to be placed into this list
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified collection is null
 */
public LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    this();
    addAll(c);
}
```

Вопрос: зачем в этом конструкторе выполняется вызов конструктора по умолчанию с помощью `this()`, ведь в конструкторе по умолчанию ничего не объявлено?

Comment: Возможно ответ на ваш вопрос [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31775424/linkedlist-data-structure-why-we-need-to-call-empty-default-constructor-from-a)

Answer (score 1):

Вызов `this()` из конструктора означает вызов конструктора без параметров, который должен выполняться перед тем, как выполнится конструктор с параметрами. Такой конструктор должен быть явно задан, чтобы можно было его вызвать.

То есть если вы хотите использовать конструктор без параметров для создания объектов класса в котором есть конструктор с параметрами, то вы должны явно определить такой конструктор, иначе вы не сможете создать объект, используя конструктор без параметров. Это вызвано тем, что конструктор по умолчанию, который тоже без параметров, не существует больше, если задан конструктор с параметрами. И для того, чтобы иметь возможность вызвать, он определяется явно.

Вызов конструктора без параметров из конструктора с параметрами делается для того, чтобы даже классы наследники могли использовать конструктор без параметров при создании объектов.

Comment: "который должен выполняться перед тем, как выполнится конструктор с параметрами." зачем пустой конструктор должен выполняться, он же ничего не делает?

Comment: Я дополнил ответ, если ты не понял. Пустой или не пустой не имеет значения.

Comment: "Вызов конструктора без параметров из конструктора с параметрами делается для того, чтобы даже классы наследники могли использовать конструктор без параметров" это никак не проясняет то, зачем вызывать конструктор, который ничего не делает. если бы в конструкторе без аргументов выполнялись какие-то дополнительные действия, это другое дело. но ведь конструктор без аргументов абсолютно ничего не делает

Comment: тем более, при создании объекта-наследника он использует конструктор предка без аргументов. конструктор с аргументами при создании наследника не используется => нет никакой необходимости явного вызова `this()`

Comment: Пустой конструктор без аргументов нужен для того, чтобы вы могли создать пустой LinkedList. Т к определен конструктор с параметрами, то по умолчанию конструктора без параметров теперь не существует и при попытке сделать new LinkedList() вы получите ошибку.

Comment: Если в наследнике переопределить конструктор без параметров, то он будет вызван при создании LinkedList с параметрами.

Comment: @Григорий "Пустой конструктор без аргументов нужен для того, чтобы..." мой вопрос же был совсем о другом...

Comment: В следуйщем комменте про то зачем вызов пустого конструктора